# how function overloading works

Tags: c++

```
int add(int a,int b)
{
     cout<<"1"<<endl;
     return a+b;
 }
 int add(int a,char c)
 {
       cout<<"2"<<endl;
      return a+c;
 }
int main()
{
          cout<<add(10,20)<<endl;    //1
          cout<<add(10,'a')<<endl;   //2 
          cout<<add('a','b')<<endl;  //3 
 }
```

in the above code the first function calls function add(int,int) ,the second function calls function add(int,char).
the third function call should result as error but it calls the function add(int,char).
can any one explain why.

Comment: c++ is weakly typed. The compiler will do its best to make the code work without errors, so in this case it automatically casts the char input as an int.

Comment: @Kapura That's not what weakly typed means.

Answer (score 5):

there is implicit conversion char to int. More here:

http://www.petebecker.com/js/js200004.html

implicit conversion is :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Answer (score 1):

If all parameters of one function convert at least as well as those of another function and some of the parameters convert better, that function is taken.

If not all parameters convert at least as well as those of another function, and not all the parameters of the latter function convert at least as well as those of the former function, there is an ambiguity risen in the normal case of plain functions.

Answer (score 0):

The closest match is the one with int and char. Since a char can be implicitly converted to an int it still works.

```
int a = 'a'; // Returns the ascii value for 'a'.
```

Comment: I'd dub it "numeric value", since ASCII isn't a given.